# Cannot seem to find the index where regex gets a match

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm using vb.net and something that seems obvious in PHP does not work (for me) in vb.net:

```
Extract = "100011100000"
Dim HandReg3 As New Regex("(?:[0]*)(1{3,})(?:[0]*)")

If HandReg3.IsMatch(Extract) Then
     Dim m() As String = HandReg3.Split(Extract)
     For Each item As String In m
         Console.WriteLine(item)
     Next
     Dim m1 As Match = Regex.Match(Extract, "(?:[0]*)(1{3,})(?:[0]*)")
     Console.WriteLine(m1.Index)
     Console.WriteLine(m1.Length)
End If
```

Which writes:

```
1
111
1  <-Index. Shouldn't it be 4 (0 based) or 5????
111
```

I've tried several combinations of groups (capturing and not capturing).
Of course it has to be something obvious and stupid but after almost 8 hours. I just can't get it right!
Tried:

```
([0-1]*)(1{3,})([0-1]*)
[0-1]*1{3,}[0-1]*
```

and every other combination that I can thought of in between.

Thanks for your help

Emiliano

Comment: You say VB.NET code works differently than PHP - then what is the PHP code that works?

Comment: I do not see any issue here: the match starts after the first `1`, at Position 2, so you get `m1.Index=1` correctly.

Comment: Since Extract = "100011100000" the match is at position 5 not 1 (IMHO).

Comment: Maybe you meant to read the value of `m1.Group(1).Index`  and `m1.Groups(1).Length` instead? `Group(1).Index` should return `4` here and `Group(1).Length` is `3` (same as just `1{3,}`).

Comment: AAARGGGGGGGG!   That was it.  m1.Groups(1).index is the solution Thanks :)